# Python ogr filter attribute SQL

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, ogr

I have a shapefile with 4 attribute fields (MC_ID, MC_info, C_ID, C_info).

I want to change some MC_ID values selecting the features by C_info.

For example: I want to set MC_ID = 2 for C_info = g19, C_info = g22 and C_info = g23.

The problem is that I am not succeeding in filtering the shapefile.
If I set

```
mylayer.SetAttributeFilter("C_info = 'g19'" or "C_info = 'g22'" or "C_info = 'g23'")
```

it filters only one feature (the first one).

I also tried to use the command ExecuteSQL

```
result = dataSource.ExecuteSQL("select * from roi_classMacro WHERE C_info = 'g19'" or "C_info = 'g22'" or "C_info = 'g23')
```

and also

```
result = dataSource.ExecuteSQL("select * from roi_classMacro WHERE (C_info = 'g19') or (C_info = 'g22')")
```

but it returns me NoneType (in the second case QGIS crashes).

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL query is wrong, it should be:

```
result = dataSource.ExecuteSQL("select * from roi_classMacro WHERE C_info = 'g19' or C_info = 'g22' or C_info = 'g23'")
```

For attribute filter try:

```
mylayer.SetAttributeFilter("C_info = 'g19' or C_info = 'g22' or C_info = 'g23'")
```

Comment: I made a very stupid error and I didn't realize it.  :)


Thank you very much @dmh126 for your help.